# difference between matchCreated and beforeMatchFired method in drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine

What is difference between `matchCreated(MatchCreatedEvent evnt)` and  `beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent evnt)` method in drools AgendaEventListener.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event "match created" means that a rule and a set of facts have been combined and put on the agenda, because the facts match the conditions of that rule. This combination may stay a short or long while on the agenda, until its time has come for being "fired", i.e., its right hand side to be executed *or* until changes in the fact set remove the activation from the agenda *or* the session is halted.

The event "before match fired" applies to the first possibility mentioned previously, i.e., the execution of the right hand side is about to begin.